# minted Perl with dollar symbol

Tags: luatex, minted, perl

I'm using minted to display some Perl, however the "unmatched" '$' in it is breaking compilation. Escaping it with a '\' results in the \ being displayed with the rest of the code block.

Is there a way to do this?

`\mint{perl}{$_[0]}`

Comment: As far as I know, `\mintinline` is only in the development version of `minted`. As such, this question is mostly off topic, because `\mintinline` is not an “official” feature. Why don't you try `pythontex`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it seems i'm using v2.0-alpha3. I haven't heard of pythontex before, but i'll take a look

Comment: I changed it so it's not about \mintinline, as that's not really relevant to the question

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the special characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

\mint{perl}|$_[0]|

\end{document}
```

The character `|` stands for an arbitrary (nonspecial) character that doesn't appear in the text to be processed, like for `\verb`.

You might consider using `pythontex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\pygment{perl}|$_[0]|

\end{document}
```

This requires, instead of running `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option, running the postprocessor `pythontex`:

```
pdflatex filename
pythontex filename
pdflatex filename
```

Running `pythontex` is necessary only if some new code is added or existing code has been modified.

In this particular case, also

```
\pygment{perl}{$_[0]}
```

works.

[image]

The result is the same with both packages, because they both use `pygmentize`.

Comment: i cannot seem to use \pygment (with minted) - the command isn't recognised

Comment: @LordAro No, `\pygment` is a command for `pythontex`. My last remark is about how the packages obtain the result.

Comment: ah, i see. however, i can't seem to use the || with mintinline, just results in the same error

Comment: actually, the \pygments method doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

It's a disgusting way, but I got it to work:

`\texttt{\$}\mintinline{perl}{_[0]}`

I only need it in black and white, so it looks fine.

If there's another answer that works better, I will accept that one instead

Comment: `\mintinline{perl}{$_[0]}` works fine for me. What packages are you loading? There might be some sort of conflict.

Comment: \usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{minted}

Comment: That preamble works for me. You might add a complete minimal document that reproduces the error to your question, or open a new question specifically about the `\mintinline`. It would also be good to see the commands you are using for compiling, and the error message.